How to show $\frac{1}{t_2-t_1}\ln \frac{C_1e^{rt_2}-1}{C_1e^{rt_1}-1} \le C$?
For fixed $r>0, C_1>1$, how to show there is constant $C>0$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{t_2-t_1}\ln \frac{C_1e^{rt_2}-1}{C_1e^{rt_1}-1}   \le C
$$
for any $0<t_1<t_2$ ?
The problem is from the picture below, I have no idea to deal it. Thanks for any help or hint.




$\frac{ \ln C_1 e^{rt_2} -1  - \ln C_1 e^{rt_1} -1 } { t_2 - t_1 }$ looks like ....

@CalvinLin  like derivative, thanks  ;-)

Intuitively, $f(t) = \ln(C_1e^{rt}-1)\implies $ $f'(t) = \dfrac{rC_1e^{rt}}{C_1e^{rt}-1} = r+\dfrac{r-1}{C_1e^{rt}-1}<r+\dfrac{r-1}{C_1-1} = C$ has a bounded derivative so the ratios $\dfrac{f(t_2)-f(t_1)}{t_2-t_1}$ is "more-or-less" bounded.
Rigorously, you can see $f''<0$ and so it lies below the tangent line at point $t_1:$
$$f(t_2)\leq (t_2-t_1)f'(t_1) +  f(t_1)\implies \dfrac{f(t_2)-f(t_1)}{t_2-t_1}\leq f'(t_1)\leq C.$$
